# Redefine/Reset columns in flexigrid?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

how to dynamically redefine columns in flexigrid?

i have tried the followings:

```
model = [{ .../*some new columns model*/ } ];

target.flexOptions({colModel: model});
target.flexReload();
```

without any luck :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this same problem.

The bes I could do was create a wrapper div for the flexigrid's div and empty the wrapper/recreate the flexigrid everytime I needed to change the colmodel. Something like:

```
$("#flexigridContainer").empty();
$("#flexigridContainer").append($("<div>").attr("id", "reporteFlexigrid"));

var report = $("#cmbValReports option:selected").attr("value");
var colModel;
switch(report){
    case 1: url = ""; colModel = abonosFlexigridModel(); break;
    case 2: url = ""; colModel = cgeneralFlexigridModel(); break;
    case 3: url = ""; colModel = cccostoFlexigridModel(); break;
    case 4: url = ""; colModel = prestamoFlexigridModel(); break;
}

    initFlexigrid(url, colModel);
```

And the initFlexigrid was something like

```
function initFlexigrid(purl, pcolModel){
$("#reporteFlexigrid").flexigrid({url: purl, colModel: pcolModel, ... }); }
```

It worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  model = [{ .../*some new columns model*/ } ];
  $('#flex').flexOptions(model).flexReload();
```

Comment: nope , this doesn't work, i have worked around it by predefining all the columns first and hide it :)